# Get substring before a specified substring

Tags: php, string, text-extraction

```
$title = 'the.test.hd.part12';
```

I need to keep the characters up until it finds the word "part".

Should return - `the.test.hd.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo strstr($title, 'part', true); // As of PHP 5.3.0`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo current(explode('part12',$title));
```

Comment: The search string is `part`, not `part12`.

Answer (score 0):

For users on PHP Version < 5.3.0:

`echo substr($title, 0, strpos($title, $needle));`

Comment: This is not false-safe.  If the needle is not found, no precautions have been taken to avoid a logical error.